# timer.scheduleAtFixedRate have an exception

Tags: java, android, timer

my code is:

```
ou=100
final Timer t=new Timer();
TimerTask tt=new TimerTask() {              
       @Override
       public void run() {
           ou-=10;
           if(ou==0)
               btnstart.setText(btnstart.getText().toString()+"t");

      }};
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 2000, 2000);
```

but when I run this program when change btnstart.text program will be close with this error "unfortunately, has stopped"

this is my log cat:

> 07-01 15:27:30.714: W/dalvikvm(973): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
>   07-01 15:27:30.786: E/AndroidRuntime(973): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
>   07-01 15:27:30.786: E/AndroidRuntime(973): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>   07-01 15:27:30.786: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
>   07-01 15:27:30.786: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:322)
>   07-01 15:27:30.786: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:91)
>   07-01 15:27:30.786: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
>   07-01 15:27:30.786: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at ir.maghsoodi.reminders.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:45)
>   07-01 15:27:30.786: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimerTask` is executed in another Thread (TimerThread) and you can't update `UI` elements from a thread which is not the main.

Use `btnstart.post( Runnable )` to execute the code inside UI Thread.

Example

```
if(ou==0) {
 btnstart.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     btnstart.setText(btnstart.getText().toString()+"t");
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: how can I do that?  can you explain more?

Comment: how can I send a toast instead of change text of button?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html (p.s For a new problem ask another question)

Answer (score 1):

You can not update the UI from another thread, you need to use an Handler as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html), or (much easier in my opinion) use the [eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library

Comment: how can I do that? can you explain more?